# Timeout Error while using Command Queue

Tags: ssd, block-device, nvme, mmc, mqueue

I am new to command queue mechanism in Linux. I am using the following:

Kernel Tree: git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm
Kernel Ver: 4.9.96

While doing read/write I observe a timeout error:

```
mmc0: request with tag: 30 flags: 0x2469000 timed out
mmc0: mmc_blk_cmdq_complete_rq: txfr error(-110)/resp_err(0)
mmc0: mmc_blk_cmdq_complete_rq err req = 0xffffffc0f82acda0, err = -110, err tag = 16
mmc0: mmc_blk_cmdq_err err req = ffffffc0f82acda0, err tag = 16
```

I checked the CQ registers dump:
Following are some of the important ones:

```
CQTDBR: 0x7fffffff
CQDPT: 0x7fffffff
CQCRI: 0x0000000d
```

What may have caused this error and how to solve it ?

Thanks in advance.